# speechSynthesis.getVoices returns an empty array in the console on Ubuntu 22.04 and Firefox/Chromium

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, ubuntu-22.04

Since I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I can't use TTS on the browser.

I have read the similar issues, and they usually say that you need to wait for the voices to load. But on my case, I can wait as much as I want, it will always return the same empty array

[image]

Notice that I have:

```
$ spd-say -O
OUTPUT MODULES
espeak-ng
```

And that

```
spd-say -L
                     NAME                 LANGUAGE                  VARIANT
                Afrikaans                       af                     none
         Afrikaans+Andrea                       af                   Andrea
          Afrikaans+Annie                       af                    Annie
        Afrikaans+Antonio                       af                  Antonio
         Afrikaans+Auntie                       af                   Auntie
        Afrikaans+Belinda                       af                  Belinda
          Afrikaans+Boris                       af                    Boris
...
```

So, my system correctly handles the voice recognition, and I can even call `spd-say "Hello World". It's as if the browser could not access the speech engine...

I don't know what I can do next. Any idea?

Comment: Same problem for me in kubuntu for all browsers (chromium and firefox). For firefox there is the following issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1666703